# How can i put down redstone dust next to a piston without it connecting?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I was trying to make a water elevator, and the tutorial put the redstone dust next to the piston and it didn't connect. But when I tried it, the dust connected to the piston. I was wondering how I place the dust without it connecting to the piston?

Comment: By playing Java edition instead. :D There is doesn't connect. But MCJava has lots of other problems with pistons, so maybe not.

Comment: Sometimes you can make your redstone wire go up or down a bit, but that depends on your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using redstone dust, you could replace the redstone next to the piston with a repeater

Comment: Hi Bloodbeast 234. Could you elaborate on your answer please? Perhaps add a screenshot, if you can.

Comment: It's just two blocks, I don't think a screenshot is needed.